# Can someone please explain what does copy function do?

Tags: c++

```
int * result = new int[size1 + size2];
copy(arr1, arr1 + size1, result);
copy(arr2, arr2 + size2, result + size1);
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12791344/6268615

Can someone explain more detail on the parameter? I've gone through the documentation of c++ but still don't understand it.

This code is merging two arrays into one dynamic arrays by using copy function.

Comment: “This code is merging two arrays into one dynamic arrays by using copy function.”  Sounds like your understood it already.  What is your question?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, I don't understand about the parameter that taken into the functions.

Comment: I recommend you draw out the arrays involved on paper, especially `result`. Then use arrows for the pointers you have, especially `result + size1`.

Comment: You can also do the same thing with `copy(arr2, arr2 + size2, copy(arr1, arr1 + size1, result));` because `copy` returns the position after the just copied elements. Does that help? Probably not.

Comment: you should read about dynamic allocation of memory ,here with the help of new operator ,memory is allocated  equal to the sizeof size1 + size2  and the copy function takes 3 parameters first base address ,second address of location in array till where we have to copy it,and third argument is where should it be copied means address of location in resultant array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this is what the parameter of [copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) mean:

```
copy( StartPositionSource, EndPositionSource, StartPositionTarget )
```

You copy from Source to Target.

Given your Example:

```
copy(arr1, arr1 + size1, result);
copy(arr2, arr2 + size2, result + size1);
```

and assuming arr1 has 2 elements and arr2 has 3 elements you get:

```
result = [arr1[0], arr1[1], arr2[0], arr2[1], arr2[2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic array pointed to by `result` is large enough to contain both `arr1` and `arr2` one after the other. The first `copy`:

```
copy(arr1, arr1 + size1, result);
```

copies each element in the range `[arr1, arr1 + size1)` starting from the position in the dynamic array pointed to by `result`, i.e., the first element of the dynamic array.

Once `arr1` has been copied into `[result, result + size1)`, you want to copy `arr2` starting from `result + size1`. This is achieved by means of:

```
copy(arr2, arr2 + size2, result + size1);
```

Comment: `result` is not an array.

Comment: Ops, you are right, the array has been dynamically allocated. Corrected :) thank you!

Comment: "the array has been dynamically allocated." there is no such thing like a "dynamically allocated array".

Comment: How would you define a heap-allocated, anonymous array (as in `new int[size1 + size2]`)?

Comment: allocated memory

Comment: @Swordfish: Yes and no. The memory is allocated to hold a collection of elements identified by an index, which is exactly the definition of "array".

Comment: Or look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector : 1) std::vector is a sequence container that encapsulates dynamic size arrays.

Comment: Skimming through the C++14 draft, 3.7.4 reads _"Objects can be created dynamically during program execution (1.9), using new-expression (5.3.4)"_. Section 11.2.2 in "The C++ Programming Language" reads: _"Arrays of objects can also be created using new."_. The [StackOverflow own FAQ on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c) adopts the term _dynamic arrays_ when referring to expressions such as `new int[N]`.

Comment: I still don't feel comfortable calling a pinter an array.

Comment: Why would you call a pointer an array? A pointer is a way to access an array. That is totally different.

Comment: I am not saying that `result` is an array. Your first comment still applies, `result` is a pointer, which retains the memory address of the first element of a heap-allocated, anonymous array of size `size1 + size2`.